# Define Differentiability on a open interval (a,b)

Tags: derivatives

Hi guys just wanted to clear up this notion of differentiable on an open interval (a,b). I do know for a closed interval you can define a closed interval as being differentiable if it can be differentiated at its end points as well as its interior points now considering that for a open interval the proper definition for an open interval being differentiable is it where its differentiable on its interior points. Can someone clear this up and just correct me to the proper definition of differentiable on a open interval?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly confuses you by differentiating on open intervals?

Comment: the definition of differentiability on an open interval ? @Allawonder

Comment: It's differentiable on an interval if it is differentiable at every point of the interval.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer @saulspatz